# why does my dialog box only work one time?

Tags: jquery

i have a dialog box and in it, it has two buttons, one that continues and one that cancels.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[name=resetPwd]").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("userid");
    var email = $("[field=emailAddress].[userid="+id+"]").text();
    var name = $("[field=firstName].[userid="+id+"]").text();

    var message = $('<div></div>')
    .html('You are about to reset the password for:<br/>'+name+'.<br/>This will send an e-mail to:<br/>'+
            email+'<br/><br/><input id="_continue" type="button" value="Continue" /> <input id="_cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />')
    .dialog({
        title: 'Reset Password'
    });

    message.dialog('open');


    $("#_cancel").click(function(){
        message.dialog('close');
    });

});
```

it works just fine, (the first time) all my data is there, when i click cancel, it closes, but if i try again cancel doesnt do anything anymore. does anyone know what im doing wrong? please and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new dialog object each time you click the resetPwd element.

You should create the dialog outside of the click handler, and just reference it using open and close methods.

Comment: when i create the dialog outside the click handler, it auto opens on every page. is there a way for it to only be available for this one page im working on?

Answer (score 1):

Try to move `$("#_cancel").click` out of the `$("[name=resetPwd]").click` body function. Also, you are not properly ending the `$(document).ready` function.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[name=resetPwd]").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("userid");
        var email = $("[field=emailAddress].[userid="+id+"]").text();
        var name = $("[field=firstName].[userid="+id+"]").text();

        var message = $('#message')
        .html('You are about to reset the password for:<br/>'+name+'.<br/>This will send an e-mail to:<br/>'+
                email+'<br/><br/><input id="_continue" type="button" value="Continue" /> <input id="_cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />')
        .dialog({
            title: 'Reset Password'
        });

        message.dialog('open');
    });
    $("#_cancel").click(function(){
        $('#message').dialog('close');
    });
});
```

EDIT: Create an empty div with id=message and try the updated code.

Comment: i think that if i have the cancel click handler before the buttons are even made, the handler wont ever find them.. is this true? i think this because the button just doesnt work... should i do a mix of the current 2 answers?